# Correctly set a context menu inside of a template

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I am trying to setup a control template that allows me to add a context menu to an element. Trouble is the only way I can figure out how to do it is by nesting TWO LABELS.

This is my style:

```
    <Style x:Key="RightClickMenu" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                <Label Name="RightClickElement">
                    <Label.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                                <MenuItem x:Name="CopyMenuItem" Command="{Binding DataContext.OnCopyCommand}"  InputGestureText="Ctrl+C" Header="Copy" />
                                <MenuItem x:Name="PasteMenuItem" Command="{Binding DataContext.OnPasteCommand}" InputGestureText="Ctrl+P" Header="Paste" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                    </Label.ContextMenu>
                </Label>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now the only way to get this into a label is by doing:

```
<Expander Name="ExpanderControl" Margin="5,5,5,5">
    <Expander.Header>           
        <Label x:Name="LabelTemplate" Style="{StaticResource RightClickMenu}" />
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

Which means I end up with  which is a bit rubbish. Plus it means I cant define this context menu for other controls!

How can I specify that my expnder header has a template. Which is just a single label?

Comment: Maybe contentpresenter is what I need?

Comment: What is your question?